# PhDc - how long can you use it if it has not been completed?

Tags: all-but-dissertation

Many things came up during my PhD program, including personal and a horrible committee chair after two of mine left for other schools. I completed all my coursework, successfully completed my comps, and had all 3 chapters written and was in process of editing my chapters when they cut me off as it had been 5 years. I had a case against the school but the time to go to court and money it would cost would be enormous. It ended up that my advisor was retiring. When I apply for other jobs, I was a PhDc. How long can that be used for. I'm not claiming i have my PhD but want to claim I was a candidate. I am now back in school for a different doctorate, so until that is completed, I want to use PhDc. Thoughts on legality of this - has anyone done this?

Comment: When will you be admitted to candidacy in the new program?

Answer (score 6):

I'd guess that you need to spell it out more completely. PhDc isn't really recognized and it isn't a degree or anything like a degree.

In many institutions, you have a limited time to complete your degree unless you take some special actions. Seven years, perhaps, in the US, shorter elsewhere. After that time, you are no longer a candidate for anything. If they "cut you off" after five years, I doubt that the institution considers you a candidate and it would be dishonest to claim otherwise.

Perhaps there is some way you can get back in line for your degree. ABD is a descriptive term, not an honor. Perhaps you can use what you know to get in to a different program and complete it.

Answer (score 5):

You were at one time a PhD candidate, but you currently are not one. There is nothing wrong in stating that you achieved PhD candidacy in your previous course of study and listing it on your CV as such, but it would be wrong to present yourself as a PhD candidate, since you are not one. There's no limitation on how long you can claim you *were* a PhDc, as that's going to be true at all points in the future, but you shouldn't give the impression that you *are* a current candidate for a PhD. To give a parallel scenario, if someone introduced themselves as a "candidate for mayor", I would be very surprised to learn that they had run and lost their election years prior. Just be clear about the time frame in which the title was applicable.

As for the legality, "PhD candidate" isn't a legally protected title as far as I know, so running into legal repercussions seems very unlikely. There could potentially be a case for fraud if you materially misrepresent your qualifications for your own personal gain, but this again seems like a rather unlikely scenario, as I've never seen "PhD candidacy" be a salient requirement for a job. Legal consequences for an embellished resume seem uncommon and reserved for egregious cases (like claiming a medical degree that you don't have), claiming a different level of being a student is probably not going to land you in court.

Answer (score 3):

You can list it under the "Experience" section of your CV. Something like this:

- Company: **University Name**
- Position: **Research Assistant**

  - Description Point 1: ...
  - Description Point 2: ...
  - Description Point 3: ...

PhDc doesn't mean anything. Don't use it.